# LOAD HADOOP fails while pulling from Teradata

Tags: hadoop, teradata, bigsql

I am using IBM BigInsights version 4.1.0.

I used the below command to pull data from teradata.

```html
LOAD HADOOP USING JDBC CONNECTION URL 'jdbc:teradata://<<ip_address>>/database=<<db_name>>' WITH PARAMETERS ('user' = '<<user_name>>','password'='<<password>>') FROM TABLE <<table_name>> COLUMNS (<<COL1, COL2, COL3, .... COLN>>) SPLIT COLUMN <<COLM>> INTO TABLE <<Target_bigsql_schema>>.<<target_bigsql_table>> APPEND WITH LOAD PROPERTIES ('tdch.enable'='true');
```

The error I am getting while executing the above command is below

```html
2015-12-10 14:21:01,336 ERROR com.ibm.biginsights.ie.sqoop.td.wrapper.TDImportTool [Thread-3] : Teradata Connector for Hadoop tool error.
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:88)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:618)
        at com.ibm.biginsights.ie.sqoop.td.wrapper.TDImportTool.callTDCH(TDImportTool.java:104)
        at com.ibm.biginsights.ie.sqoop.td.wrapper.TDImportTool.run(TDImportTool.java:72)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:143)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:179)
        at com.ibm.biginsights.ie.db.SqoopUtils.runSqoopTool(SqoopUtils.java:146)
        at com.ibm.biginsights.ie.db.DBImportImpl.importData(DBImportImpl.java:159)
        at com.ibm.biginsights.ie.impl.ImporterImpl.executeImport(ImporterImpl.java:504)
        at com.ibm.biginsights.ie.impl.ImporterImpl.executePerformImport(ImporterImpl.java:417)
        at com.ibm.biginsights.ie.impl.ImporterImpl.performImport(ImporterImpl.java:264)
        at com.ibm.biginsights.biga.udf.LoadTool.performImport(LoadTool.java:214)
        at com.ibm.biginsights.biga.udf.BIGSQL_DDL.doLoadStatement(BIGSQL_DDL.java:644)
        at com.ibm.biginsights.biga.udf.BIGSQL_DDL.processDDL(BIGSQL_DDL.java:207)
Caused by: com.teradata.connector.common.exception.ConnectorException: Hive table's InputFormat class is not supported
        at com.teradata.connector.common.tool.ConnectorJobRunner.runJob(ConnectorJobRunner.java:140)
        ... 17 more
2015-12-10 14:21:01,337 ERROR org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop [Thread-3] : Got exception running Sqoop: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.teradata.connector.common.exception.ConnectorException: Hive table's InputFormat class is not supported
2015-12-10 14:21:01,337 ERROR com.ibm.biginsights.ie.db.DBImportImpl [Thread-3] : Error during import
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.teradata.connector.common.exception.ConnectorException: Hive table's InputFormat class is not supported
        at com.ibm.biginsights.ie.sqoop.td.wrapper.TDImportTool.callTDCH(TDImportTool.java:123)
        at com.ibm.biginsights.ie.sqoop.td.wrapper.TDImportTool.run(TDImportTool.java:72)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:143)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:179)
        at com.ibm.biginsights.ie.db.SqoopUtils.runSqoopTool(SqoopUtils.java:146)
        at com.ibm.biginsights.ie.db.DBImportImpl.importData(DBImportImpl.java:159)
        at com.ibm.biginsights.ie.impl.ImporterImpl.executeImport(ImporterImpl.java:504)
        at com.ibm.biginsights.ie.impl.ImporterImpl.executePerformImport(ImporterImpl.java:417)
        at com.ibm.biginsights.ie.impl.ImporterImpl.performImport(ImporterImpl.java:264)
        at com.ibm.biginsights.biga.udf.LoadTool.performImport(LoadTool.java:214)
        at com.ibm.biginsights.biga.udf.BIGSQL_DDL.doLoadStatement(BIGSQL_DDL.java:644)
        at com.ibm.biginsights.biga.udf.BIGSQL_DDL.processDDL(BIGSQL_DDL.java:207)
Caused by: com.teradata.connector.common.exception.ConnectorException: Hive table's InputFormat class is not supported
        at com.teradata.connector.common.tool.ConnectorJobRunner.runJob(ConnectorJobRunner.java:140)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:88)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:618)
        at com.ibm.biginsights.ie.sqoop.td.wrapper.TDImportTool.callTDCH(TDImportTool.java:104)
        ... 12 more
2015-12-10 14:21:01,337 ERROR com.ibm.biginsights.ie.db.DBImportImpl [Thread-3] : [BSL-0-18c443e19]: Error during import (Job Id = ):com.teradata.connector.common.exception.ConnectorException: Hive table's InputFormat class is not supported
```

Is there any possible resolution for this?

Comment: can you provide definition of your HIVE table?

Comment: hive> desc POS_RTL_STR_TEST;
OK
rtl_str_id              int
rtl_str_lang_cd         varchar(5)
Time taken: 0.306 seconds, Fetched: 2 row(s)

Answer (score 0):

Teradata's native CHAR and VARCHAR is not supported in TDCH.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSPT3X_4.1.0/com.ibm.swg.im.infosphere.biginsights.db2biga.doc/doc/biga_load_from.html?lang=en